# Foundation img folder missing

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I am learning Foundation framework and I have some problems with my code. I am trying to output images for different devices (mobile, tablet and desk) but when i write my code (path to the images is correct - checked few times...) and try to view the outcome in localhost i cannot see my images on the screen. Lets say i go localhost/foundation and when i inspect dev. tools on chrome sub menu: Sources my IMG folder is not shown there but it is actually inside my foundation folder. 
here is my code that I am trying to run:

```
 <header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="logo" data-interchange="[img/logoS.png, (default)],[img/logoM.png, (medium)],[img/logoL.png, (large)]">test</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

[Example of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5glc.jpg)

So you can see that the folder Images is missing so I cannot add reference to it and output my images but actually the folder is in place...

Answer (score 0):

In your print screen, your image folder is named as "**images**" and in your code is "**img**". Check this.